# How to load a txt file to use as a list of data for variables in Ajax & Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web

This is my first time here on stackoverflow and I wanted to ask if anyone knew a way to load a txt file that contained the string of all the variables I wanted to use in my variable for my website. I think if show you the code it will be easier to see what I'm talking about.

```
var sc2List = "wcs_america,esltv_sc2,Nathanias,TeSLLive,Sc2tv_ru,destiny,Painuser,dreamhacksc2,idrajit,demuslim,eghuk,redbullesports,EmpireTvZERG,desRowfighting,ProTech";
```

So this is my variable that is used by this function:

```
$(".wow").click(function(){
    getStreamList(wowList);
});
```

My question is, is there a way to store wcs_america, esltv_sc2 etc into a txt file so its easier for me to store and update versus hard coding it into my index file? Thank you so much for all responses!

Comment: I'm still a little lost on why you want to hard-code all your variables into a text file?

Comment: You can do it (load a text file and use your names as variables) but I don't see any sense for doing such thing. why you need your variables in a CSV? Additionally what is `sc2List` and what is `wowList` ?

Comment: I wanted to do that to sort of hide the list of players that we use to  produce a stream player list. I thought it might be cleaner that way but I guess not. Im working on a site that plays streams from twitch.tv and I make a list of players that are currently streaming by using their twitch id which is currently stored right onto the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to files from the server.

```
$.get("myvariables.txt", function(data){
    alert("My variables are " + data);
});
```